# Recursive with cursor on psql, nothing data found

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How to use a recursive query and then using cursor to update multiple rows in postgresql. I try to return data but no data is found. Any alternative to using recursive query and cursor, or maybe better code please help me.

```
drop function proses_stock_invoice(varchar, varchar, character varying);

create or replace function proses_stock_invoice
    (p_medical_cd varchar,p_post_cd varchar, p_pstruserid character varying)
returns void
language plpgsql
as $function$
declare
    cursor_data refcursor;
    cursor_proses refcursor;
    v_medicalCd varchar(20);
    v_itemCd varchar(20);
    v_quantity numeric(10);
begin
    open cursor_data for 
        with recursive hasil(idnya, level, pasien_cd, id_root) as (
            select medical_cd, 1, pasien_cd, medical_root_cd
            from trx_medical
            where medical_cd = p_pstruserid
        union all 
            select A.medical_cd, level + 1, A.pasien_cd, A.medical_root_cd
            from trx_medical A, hasil B
            where A.medical_root_cd = B.idnya
        )
        select idnya from hasil where level >=1;
    fetch next from cursor_data into v_medicalCd;
    return v_medicalCd;

    while (found)
    loop
        open cursor_proses for 
            select B.item_cd, B.quantity from trx_medical_resep A
            join trx_resep_data B on A.medical_resep_seqno = B.medical_resep_seqno
        where A.medical_cd = v_medicalCd and B.resep_tp = 'RESEP_TP_1';
        fetch next from cursor_proses into v_itemCd, v_quantity;
        while (found)
        loop
            update inv_pos_item
            set quantity = quantity - v_quantity, modi_id = p_pstruserid, modi_id = now()
            where item_cd = v_itemCd and pos_cd = p_post_cd;
        end loop;
        close cursor_proses;
    end loop;
    close cursor_data;
end 
$function$;
```

but nothing data found?

Comment: It would be better if you told us which actual problem you are trying to solve. Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and how you want that data to update. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You have a function with `return void` so it will never return any data to you. Still you have the statement `return v_medicalCd` after fetching the first record from the first cursor, so the function will return from that point and never reach the lines below.

When analyzing your function you have (1) a cursor that yields a number of `idnya` values from table `trx_medical`, which is input for (2) a cursor that yields a number of `v_itemCd, v_quantity` from tables `trx_medical_resep, trx_resep_data` for each `idnya`, which is then used to (3) update some rows in table `inv_pos_item`. You do not need cursors to do that and it is, in fact, extremely inefficient. Instead, turn the whole thing into a single update statement.

I am assuming here that you want to update an inventory of medicines by subtracting the medicines prescribed to patients from the stock in the inventory. This means that you will have to sum up prescribed amounts by type of medicine. That should look like this (note the comments):

```
CREATE FUNCTION proses_stock_invoice
    -- VVV parameter not used
    (p_medical_cd varchar, p_post_cd varchar, p_pstruserid varchar)
RETURNS void AS $function$
    UPDATE inv_pos_item                           -- VVV   column repeated   VVV
    SET quantity = quantity - prescribed.quantity, modi_id = p_pstruserid, modi_id = now()
    FROM (
        WITH RECURSIVE hasil(idnya, level, pasien_cd, id_root) AS (
                SELECT medical_cd, 1, pasien_cd, medical_root_cd
                FROM trx_medical
                WHERE medical_cd = p_pstruserid
            UNION ALL 
                SELECT A.medical_cd, level + 1, A.pasien_cd, A.medical_root_cd
                FROM trx_medical A, hasil B
                WHERE A.medical_root_cd = B.idnya
        )
        SELECT B.item_cd, sum(B.quantity) AS quantity
        FROM trx_medical_resep A
        JOIN trx_resep_data B USING (medical_resep_seqno)
        JOIN hasil ON A.medical_cd = hasil.idnya 
        WHERE B.resep_tp = 'RESEP_TP_1'
        --AND hacil.level >= 1    Useless because level is always >= 1
        GROUP BY 1
    ) prescribed
    WHERE item_cd = prescribed.item_cd
      AND pos_cd = p_post_cd;
$function$ LANGUAGE sql STRICT;
```

**Important**

As with all UPDATE statements, test this code before you run the function. You can do that by running the `prescribed` sub-query separately as a stand-alone query to ensure that it does the right thing.